# ReactJs: Cannot select item from MenuItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a case where the I have 3 items, and at in the case where is the first item, it should be displaying only the first item, and not allow the user to select 2nd and 3rd, but in case wher `isItFirt = false` then the user should be able to choose from the list. I wrote the minimal reproducible example as shown below:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  Box,
  Select,
  InputLabel,
  FormControl,
  MenuItem,
  SelectChangeEvent
} from "@mui/material";

enum MyOptions {
  FIRST = 1,
  SECOND = 2,
  THIRD = 3
}

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [myOptions, setMyOptions] = React.useState(MyOptions.SECOND as number);
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    let nr = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    setMyOptions(nr);
  };

  const isItFirst: boolean = false;

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const somethingHappens = () => {
    console.log("clicked: ", myOptions);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isItFirst) {
      setMyOptions(MyOptions.FIRST as number);
    }
  }, [isItFirst]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        size="small"
        onClick={() => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        Display dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h4">
            Select one of the options
          </Typography>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel id="1">Options</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId=""
              id=""
              value={myOptions}
              label="Options"
              onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}
            >
              {isItFirst ? (
                <MenuItem value={MyOptions.FIRST}>This is first</MenuItem>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <MenuItem value={MyOptions.SECOND} key={MyOptions.SECOND}>
                    This is second
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={MyOptions.THIRD} key={MyOptions.THIRD}>
                    This is third
                  </MenuItem>
                </div>
              )}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Box>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => {
            somethingHappens();
          }}
        >
          Select
        </Button>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the error output:

```
MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `1` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "".
```

And this is the dialog box that is shown in the case when `isItFirst === false`, I do not understand why it is shown as blank when I set the state of `myOptions` with the help of useEffect.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this document](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) for `children` prop of `Select`

> The option elements to populate the select with. Can be some MenuItem when native is false and option when native is true.
> ⚠️The MenuItem elements must be direct descendants when native is false.

So technically, we cannot pass `div` or any other elements to wrap `MenuItem`.

For the fix, you can consider to use `filter` and `map` with a pre-defined option like below

```
const options: {value: MyOptions, label: string}[] = [
  {value: MyOptions.FIRST, label: "This is first"},
  {value: MyOptions.SECOND, label: "This is second"},
  {value: MyOptions.THIRD, label: "This is thrid"}
]
```

Here is how we apply options to `Select`

```
<Select
  labelId=""
  id=""
  value={myOptions}
  label="Options"
  onChange={handleChange}
  key="first-select"
>
  {options
    .filter((option) =>
      isItFirst
        ? option.value === MyOptions.FIRST
        : option.value !== MyOptions.FIRST
    )
    .map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
        {option.label}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
```